# Direct user to url.com/page have url select div # from URL

Tags: javascript, php, html

I dont know how to 'title' this question.

I never have had to do this, so am having troubles finding a good source on SO or google.

I have a tab `<li><a href="#Tasks" data-toggle="tab">Tasks</a></li>`

I would like to use a URL link to direct user to this specific tab.

www.site.com/page?params=blah&parms=blah`#Tasks` and have it automatically pull this specifc tab back up.

Reason I am trying to do this is because if the user clicks on a button, it will post to db via PDO, then once finished redirect user to the specific page. I would like it to redirect user to the page, and select the 'tab' `#Tasks`.

This question seems weak, but it is legitimate, and hope its not instantly downvoted because of its simplicity.

```
       <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#Info" data-toggle="tab">Info</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#Tasks" data-toggle="tab">Tasks</a></li>
                </ul>
           </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: what type of output is you need?

Comment: Are you trying to navigate to the tab or display/make active that tab?

Comment: I am trying to display/make active that tab @AyoK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this :
Check for fragment on page :

```
if(window.location.hash) {
     $('.nav .nav-tabs li').removeClass('active');
     var fragment;
     //you can confirm if the hash contains  #Tasks
     if(fragment === "Tasks"){
          $("#tasks").addClass('active');
     }

 } 

  <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active" id="info"><a href="#Info" data-toggle="tab">Info</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Tasks" id="tasks" data-toggle="tab">Tasks</a></li>
            </ul>
       </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: So in my url I would call www.site.com/page#taskTab ? or Tasks? // Not able to get to work... hrmm...

Comment: Not necessarily just make sure that it's the right id you are making active. Can you post the full html for your tabs

Comment: I have updated the OP with the full snippet of my tabs. @AyoK

Answer (score 0):

First give a unique id to that Tasks `<li>`

```
<li id="TabTasks"><a href="#Tasks" data-toggle="tab">Tasks</a></li>
```

then put this in the bottom of your page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.location.hash.substring(1)=="Tasks")
{
    $("#TabTasks").click();
}
</script>
```

This will simulate a click on that `<li>` and your script will handle the presentation (making your tab active etc)

edit: if that `id="TabTasks"` doesnt work in the `li`, try putting it in the `a` instead. like this:

```
<li><a id="TabTasks" href="#Tasks" data-toggle="tab">Tasks</a></li>
```

Comment: @Levi try put that `id="TabTasks"` into the `<a href="#Tasks" data-toggle="tab">` maybe that's the element that triggers your script. so make it like `<li><a id="TabTasks" href="#Tasks" data-toggle="tab">Tasks</a></li>` (don't forget to remove the `id="TabTasks"` from the `<li>` if you previously put that there)